# How can I view all events for a particular Session when I am using Event Tracking in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Event Tracking to track various clicks by the user. e.g. whether the user clicked on the next button, submit button, categories menu link, filter control link etc.

Google Analytics bundles the events and shows them together for all user sessions. IS it possible to view the events for a particular user session only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really how Google Analytics models its data; the focus tends to be on aggregated metrics, rather than disaggregated ones.

That said: This could be possible if you have some filtering mechanism by which to filter down to a session level.

For example, if you have some sort of custom variable with unique values, you could create an Advanced Segment for sessions with that custom variable value.

However, this data is unlikely to be perfect, as drilling down too specifically could trigger "fast access mode", where GA uses sampled, rather than raw, data to provide a faster snapshot of the data you're looking for.